# Where can I detected a USB devices connected to an Android phone using adb(Rooted Phone)?

Tags: android, adb

So I am connected via adb over WiFi. Now I connected a thumb drive to the USBc port but I don't know where in the device directories I can find the external attached USB. It will be nice if I can get some help to find under what directory in the Android system the external thumb drive appears?

```
>> adb shell
```

Comment: are the answers below helping in figuring out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The common way to list USB devices in a Linux shell is simply `lsusb`. However, this only helps when developing for NDK. For SDK you can forget about `adb shell` altogether and just use [`UsbManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager) instead, which already nicely abstracts the USB sub-system, ready to use within a SDK application.